Auto Generate unique Alpha Numeric string in JavaScript or python
Is there a way to automatically generate unique Alpha numeric string which does not repeat from all the previously auto generated string?
I'm saving this auto generated string in a DB
In my current behavior there are some auto generated string which are already in stored
Any help would be appreciated
Thanks in Advance

of course there is. Just make a loop that starts with the string "AAAAAAAAAA" and increases the last character, so the next iterations are "AAAAAAAAAB", "AAAAAAAAAC". Once it reaches Z increase the previous character by one and reset the ones to the right back to "A".   The strings will not repeat until you reach "ZZZZZZZZZZ" and overflow back to "AAAAAAAAAA". Increase the string lenght if you need more unique strings. This solution satisfies the requisites from your question, and is language agnostic, so you can easily implement it in python or javascript

You can use uuid.
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
uuidv4(); // ⇨ '9b1deb4d-3b7d-4bad-9bdd-2b0d7b3dcb6d'


Just for completeness: in Python, one could achieve the same via from uuid import uuid4 and then uuid4().hex (string without hyphens) or str(uuid4()) (string with hyphens as separators).
